# How top change colors of tabBar borders when selected?

Tags: flutter

Like the image below I want to make an TabBar where there is complete border and when it is selected the borders turns blue if not it remains brown. How do I do it?? [image]

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the `indicator` property, it accepts a BoxDecoration :

```
TabBar(
// other properties
indicator: BoxDecoration(
 border: Border.all(
 width: 2,
 color: Color.blue
 ))),
```

this will set a full outlined border indicator for `tabs` in `TabBar`